# Timing issues in Python nose test

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I have some unit tests that are timing sensitive: an action is timed and an error is triggered if it takes too long. When run individually, these tests pass, but when running nosetest recursively on my modules, they often fail. I run concurrent tests, which likely is one reason why the timing is off. Is there any way to indicate that I want this test to be run with no interruptions?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is dependent from how you implemented the timing. The solution I would personally adopt would be to set an environment variable that controls the behaviour of the tests. Candidates could be:

- `if WITH_TIMING == False` [turn off timing altogether]
- `TIME_STRETCH_FACTOR = ...` [apply a time-stretching multiplier in case of concurrent test are run, so that for example a time limit of 5 would become 7.5 if `TIME_STRETCH_FACTOR` would be 1.5]

If this is not an option, a possible **ugly** workaround would be to mock the `time.time()` function, making it return a constant value [this would only work if you use `time.time()` in your tests directly of course]...

HTH